# google like search

Tags: asp.net

I want to include search functionality on my website and i was looking at a website that does something very similar to my requirement

Please have a look the the below URL and you can see at the very top of the screen there is a search  textbox.

http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/sport/football/

Can some one please advise on how i can implement similar thing fo my website

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize a google-like search engine for your site.  Google itself provides this feature.

Here's a link:
http://www.google.com/cse/

Answer (score 2):

That's a google tool you can add it from your adsense webpage.
If you have an adsense account the address is this one https://www.google.com/adsense/cse-settings

they "pay" you for using this kind of service